# how to optimize performance of mongoDB timeseries in mongo V5-V7

Tags: mongodb

i am working on a migration from usual collections to time serie collection,
i succeded to upload my data like this :

[image]

and me and my colleagues are questionning about if this really the best way to upload this, because the object header is quite big like 40 keys in a json and so we are uploading the same header like 40000 times on each different file we treat, would it be better to create a collection for the headers and then an object_id_reference into the timeserie object pointing on the good header ?

thanks in advance for your enlighted advices

Comment: If the headers are identical storing them separately is good.